# Element DOM injected won't start his own directive

Tags: angularjs, compilation, angularjs-ng-repeat, directive, digest

1. I have a `<ul>` which contains the directive ng-repeat.
2. Inside it, I have multiple "li" which contains a directive :  `<li directive>`.
3. The array (A) which serves the directive ng-repeat contains comments. And when the user adds comment, I want display its comment before all of others. For do this, I build an other array (B). I inject the new comment first, and then the comments from the array (A) after.
   In others words, I change (A) into (B) by a simple assignation (=).

The ng-repeat updates the DOM from the new content of array (A) but... but the DOM element which is binds on the directive isn't the true element, I mean the element which is in link function isn't the first comment  !

This is hard to explains this, I hope you know what I want mean.

PS: If the array (A) is empty and if I adds a comment (li) the directive binds on the true element. But if there is one or more comments, that causes the problem that I have explained.

Thx you.

Comment: *"I hope you know what I want mean"* .... no, sure don't without a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly: You have very complicat handling of the new comments.
You can:

- for each comment have some time id
- in ng-repeat use "track by commoent.timeId
- in ng-repeat use orderBy OR (little bit better) sort the comment array by the timeId after you push the new comment to array A.
  => you can remove the B array completely

Each *li* runs the directive separataly.
That means (in your solution) that after adding each new comment, the ng-repeat DOM is completely re-rendered => the directive is used for each commment.

With my proposed solution, the directive will be called only for newly added comments (as the "track by" part prevent in re-rendering unchanged comments).

... but ... I hope that I understander your problem...

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is something like:

```
<ul>
   <li ng-if="newComment">{{newComment.text}}</li>
   <li ng-repeat="comment in comments" ng-hide="comment==newComment">
       {{comment.text}}
   <li>
</ul>
```

However without a better example in question this is just rough